# Displaying python documentation of all methods and attributes with a certain word in a module

Tags: python, helper, pydoc

I am attempting to build a help system, and I would like to print all documentation of methods, from a `Python` module that contain a certain word, one after the other. This is for use in modules that have a very large number of methods or attributes. Right now this is what I am doing, for example, for a module such as Tkinter.Entry, looking for methods that have for example, 'set' in them:

```
q = []
for i in dir(Tkinter.Entry):
    if 'set' in i:
       q.append(i)
for item in q:
    help(item)
```

This shows seven items of pydoc for each method with 'set' in the name one after the other, and exits cleanly on the interpreter. However, I can't seem to be able to get the pydoc in an assignment, for example:

```
x = help(item)   # doesn't work.
# handle display code here.
```

What am I missing here?

The following is for **context**, as in not necessarily part of the question(for example):

Is there a workaround to get the same effect as this on, for example, a simple `html` that will show the next help item every time the user clicks, 'close' on the current element?

```
<html>
  <head> 
    Help page 
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $ function closediv(){
      <!-- code to close the div goes here-->
      }
  </script>
  <body>
    <!--maybe a list of divs here-->
    <div id="help text">{% block content %} {{x}} {% endblock %}</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

As long as I can get a way to find out a way to get the help text in a way that can be passed to the block content `{{X}}`, I will try to figure the rest out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `.__doc__` to get a pretty good understanding of some key terms:

```
>>> print pow.__doc__
pow(x, y[, z]) -> number

With two arguments, equivalent to x**y.  With three arguments,
equivalent to (x**y) % z, but may be more efficient (e.g. for longs).
>>> print list.__doc__
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
>>>
```

Just `help(item)` will not work with [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html). This is the same with `.__doc__`:

```
>>> help(if)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    help(if)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if.__doc__
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if.__doc__
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I would suggest looking at `pydoc.py`:

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> pydoc
<module 'pydoc' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.pyc'>
>>>
```

Which has all the documentation for everything, including simple statements.

Comment: Thanks, it appears there's a method `pydoc.getdoc` that returns a string version of the pydoc.
    `x = pydoc.getdoc(Tkinter.Entry)`
    `x`
    `'Entry widget which allows to display simple text.'`

Comment: @CoriolisForce if this answer helped you, would you mind [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the green check next to my answer? Full disclosure: it gives **you** +2 reputation :)